# Laravel get helper class from register provider

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I was trying do some service like in symfony, i was follow some tutorial and was do following steps:
1. create a new service provider:

```
namespace App\Providers;

use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;

class HelperServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * Bootstrap the application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot()
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Register the application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function register()
    {
        $this->app->bind('mailer.helper', function ($app){
            return new \App\Helpers\MailerHelper($app->make('\Illuminate\Mail\Mailer'));
        });
    }
}
```

2. i was create my custom helper:

   namespace App\Helpers;

   class MailerHelper implements \Illuminate\Contracts\Bus\SelfHandling{

   ```
   /** @var \Illuminate\Mail\Mailer $mailer */
   protected $mailer;

   public function __construct(\Illuminate\Mail\Mailer $mailer) {
       $this->mailer=$mailer;
   }


   public function sendFromContact(array $date){
       var_dump($this->mailer);die;
   }
   ```

   }
3. i register it in config/app.php:

   ```
   'providers' => [
         ...
           \App\Providers\HelperServiceProvider::class
   ```

The big problem now is how to call it in my controller.

For example in symfony if declare a service he have a name, and in controller you can do something like this: `$this->get('your.service')` but here in Laravel how to do that ? to call my service, after that to call my function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways but simply you may try this:

```
$helper = app('mailer.helper');
```

Or call a method directly:

```
app('mailer.helper')->doSomething();
```

Which is equivalent to:

```
$helper = \App::make('mailer.helper');

$helper->callSomeMethod();
```

You can also use something like this:

```
app('App\Helpers\MailerHelper')->callAction();
```

Comment: thank you, i see this work, but now take a error and say `Class 'App\Helpers\MailerHelper' not found` but i see everthying is ok, what is problem here ?

Comment: Probably you need to do a `composer dump` from terminal if not in `psr-4`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Laravel's global `app` helper:

```php
app('mailer.helper')->sendFromContact(...);
```

---

A better option may be to forgo registering anything in the container (which also means you can get rid of the service provider completely) and instead inject your class into the controller method:

```php
public function postContact(\App\Helpers\MailerHelper $helper)
{
    $helper->sendFromContact(...);
}
```

Laravel's container will resolve your `MailerHelper` class and automatically inject an instance of the `Mailer` into it.

Comment: thank you for help, i will keep in mind this but is big project and need have many helper is hard to read a function who have many parameters.